# Read-only filesystem pod with Spring Boot application on Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a Docker container with Spring Boot 3.0.0 application running in the Kubernetes Deployment.

I have received a number of hardening rules that are required to be implemented, such as:

- do not mount `emptyDir` volumes to pods
- define `runAsNonRoot` in `securityContext` of pods
- pods must define, that their filesystem is mounted readonly using `readOnlyRootFilesystem: true` in `securityContext`

My application stores data in the database and does not need any write permissions to the filesystem, so I have tried to define `securityContext` in my Deployment using:

```yaml
securityContext:
  runAsNonRoot: true
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

However, running the Deployment failed, and it seems that the Spring Boot is trying to create some temporary directory, which of course is not allowed:

```
[2023-02-01 15:12:31.762] ERROR [main] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - 820]: Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to create tempDir. java.io.tmpdir is set to /tmp
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.createTempDir(AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /tmp/tomcat.8080.8311954706877871713: Read-only file system
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.createTempDir(AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.java:202)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I was trying to find some relevant information on the web and this tells me that read-only containers are not supported in Spring Boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8578.

There are some proposed solutions, which I cannot apply, for example to use `emptyDir` mount, or `pvc`. It does not make sense for me to mount something just because Spring Boot needs to create temporary directory.

Does anyone has experience with that and can suggest a good solution how to create Deployment with Spring Boot pod that works when `readOnlyRootFilesystem: true`?

Comment: If you need a read-only filesystem, then you must mount _something_ if you need any writable space, even in `/tmp`.  An `emptyDir` volume with a `medium: Memory` setting would be the default choice to create a tmpfs; also see the [`emptyDir` volume type documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir).

Comment: I cannot mount `emptyDir`, it is disallowed by the security policy. And I do not want to mount anything, because I do not need it, I do not want to do it just because Spring Boot needs it, does not make sense for me, not a good solution.